# AFNetworking background task not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services, afnetworking

Here is my code to post image in server with background feature but it gives error

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"com.uploadDocument.Background"];


MBProgressHUD *progres = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[[AppDelegate sharedInstance] window] animated:YES];
progres.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminateHorizontalBar;
progres.progress = 0.0;

if (!self.sessionManager) {
    _sessionManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:config];

}
NSError *error;
NSMutableURLRequest *requet= [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"url_post" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
    NSError *error1;
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] name:@"fileUpload" fileName:path mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:&error1];
    NSLog(@"%@",error1);
    NSLog(@"%@",filePath);

} error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",requet);
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [self.sessionManager uploadTaskWithRequest:requet fromFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [progres setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
    });

    NSLog(@"%f",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[AppDelegate sharedInstance].window animated:YES];
    });

}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

**Response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=**

**"Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete."** in .NET Error

Please Help me solve that

This is working but no background config.

```
[self.sessionManager POST:@"URL " parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]
                                        name:@"fileUpload"
                                    fileName:path mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

        } progress:^(NSProgress * uploadProgress) {

            NSLog(@"%f",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [progres setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
            });
        } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[AppDelegate sharedInstance].window animated:YES];
            });

        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[AppDelegate sharedInstance].window animated:YES];
            });
        }];
```

Comment: Seem to be a server issue, are you sure you are posting the file correctly. As you can see in your log you are receiving an 500 server error, this means that the server was unable to process your request.

Comment: @rckoenes pls see edit

Comment: @rckoenes they got   "Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete." is it issue from ios side ?